# Do South African Passport holders need visa to enter Abu Dhabi

Tags: visas, transit, south-african-citizens

We are travelling to South Africa from Colombo, Sri Lanka and the layover is 12 hrs.
Does the airline provide hotel accommodation for this period.

Comment: Why would they? The title of your question and your actual question are different, which do you want to know?

Comment: @Traveller Etihad still offers STPC for some connections: https://www.australianfrequentflyer.com.au/stpc/

Answer (score 1):

South Africa passport holders need a tourist or transit visa to leave the airport transit area in UAE. You don't need a visa if you remain airside.

You may [apply for the e-transit visa or e-tourist visa](https://uaevisas.etihad.com/echannels/web/client/etihad/index.html) in advance through the Etihad web site. You might wish to obtain this in advance even if you didn't plan to go landside, as visa on arrival is at the discretion of the immigration officer for nationalities that are not automatically eligible for it.

You will need to contact Etihad or check your ticket to find out if you are eligible for a free hotel stay. This is only given to passengers with tickets in certain fare classes. AFAIK [only Business and First tickets](https://www.etihad.com/en-us/plan-and-book/book-stopovers/premium-stopovers/) get a free hotel stay.